# Xamarin Forms Ui project (Multiplatform)

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms, multiplatform

I am making this UI for a multiplatform app using Xamarin on my Macbook.
I have set FormsUI as startup project.
Xamarin gives errors when i try to run the project on ios simulator.

---

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:

Error: Failed to load output manifest for ibtool: Unrecognized property list format. (XPlatformFormsUI.iOS)

---

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:

Error: Output manifest contents:  (XPlatformFormsUI.iOS)

Comment: Is it giving you this error if you create a new solution and run it without making any changes?

Comment: nope.. the project i am running is giving this error

Comment: Did  you resolve the error by now? Or have you simply created a new project and iterated each change in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular error has been mentioned in the [Xamarin Forms forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24942/cannot-compile-ios-project-since-last-update-failed-to-load-output-manifest-for-ibtool); basically, something in one of the iOS assets (e.g. a storyboard) is the cause. Unfortunately, you don't get much information regarding WHICH asset it was in the error. Try creating a brand new solution and gradually introduce your changes until you hit the error.